# laravel path error setting image source in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image

i have a problem in getting the path of my image in laravel directory in javascript. I already get the image in php but not in javascript here is in my php

```
<img src="{{ asset('image_files/' . $product->featured_img) }}" />
```

i tried in my javascript like this and i got error:

```
$("#feature_img").attr('src',asset('image_files/'+data.product[0].featured_img))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can define like this.you missed curly brace

```
  $("#feature_img").attr('src',"{{asset('image_files')}}/"+data.product[0].featured_img);
```

Comment: sorry my  mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

Get resource path and then use like this

```
var path = "{{ resource_path() }}";

$("#feature_img").attr('src',path +"/asset/image_files/"+data.product[0].featured_img);
```